# This in a Quasar project and node module not able to access this.$q

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm having trouble accessing Quasar's `this.$q` in a node module and using it as a `boot` plugin in the Quasar CLI.

I have a component where I start my QLayout where I can access `this.$q` when I put a console.log(this.$q) in the created part of that component I can access the information. But receive various errors of QLayout not being able to access that same information.

```
Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined"

found in

---> <QLayout>
       <DlLayoutMenu> at node_modules/frontend-modules/src/components/system/components/DlLayoutMenu.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined
    at VueComponent.data (QLayout.js?2d21:37)
    at VueComponent.mergedDataFn (vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:1219)
    at getData (vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:4748)
    at initData (vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:4705)
    at initState (vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:4642)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:5006)
    at new VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?794d:5154)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?5593:3283)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?5593:3114)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?5593:5978)
```

So I put a debugger on line `35` in `QLayout.js` and debug manually what the this object has but it's totally different and does not contain the key `$q`.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it, it took me a while to understand what was happening. But I created two Quasar projects with the cli. The parent project contained quasar and the module aswell. Without specifying and actually without really using quasar in the module it took the QLayout from the module `node_modules`. I could see this hard-coding a `console.log` inside the `QLayout.js` and debugging which one it was actually using. How it took this one I really don't know. However taking everything Quasar related outside the module made it work. This has some downsides that if I wanted to do something specifically inside that package without it's parent it wouldn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, resolve - reinstall by git pack docs

[ttps://github.com/quasarframework/vue-cli-plugin-quasar](https://github.com/quasarframework/vue-cli-plugin-quasar)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).